# What does it mean for an element to not have a parent?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, parent-child, pseudo-class

I'm reading the [MDN documentation for `:only-child` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-child), and there's one confusing point:

> **Note**: As originally defined, the selected element had to have a parent. Beginning with Selectors Level 4, this is no longer required.

The *Specifications* section also lists Selectors Level 4 with a comment "*Matching elements are not required to have a parent.*"

I'm scratching my head against the "element does not have a parent" description. Does it mean the `<html>` element or something like what the `:root` selector would match?

Answer (score 1):

> Does it mean the `<html>` element or something like what the `:root` selector would match?

Yep. The root element does not have a parent. Previously, this would make it not match any of the `*-child` pseudos, but as of Selectors 4, it's no longer excluded. But more importantly, this now also includes top-level shadow tree elements, which don't have an element parent and therefore were previously excluded as well. With this restriction removed, you can now select specific top-level shadow tree elements using those pseudos.

See Emilio's and Tab's replies to my www-style thread [here](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2017Sep/0010.html) from a few years ago.